# How to find out whether given object is Generic List<T> or List of List <T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, reflection

```
List<List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>> IDEnq = new List<List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>>();
List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>> IDListEnq = new List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>();

for (int i = 0; i < enq.Id.Count; i++)
{
    IDListEnq.Add(new HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "ID", FieldName = "Segment Tag", Value = enq.Id[i].SegmentTag, Mandatory = "Y", CharacterType = "A", MaxLength = 03 });
    IDListEnq.Add(new HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "01", FieldName = "ID Type", Value = enq.Id[i].IDType, Mandatory = "Y", CharacterType = "N", MaxLength = 02 });
    IDListEnq.Add(new HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>() { FieldTag = "02", FieldName = "ID Number", Value = enq.Id[i].IDNumber, Mandatory = "N", CharacterType = "P", MaxLength = 30 });
    IDEnq.Add(IDListEnq);
}
ValidateValue<List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>>(IDEnq, concaDel);


private string ValidateValue<T>(object EnqTagList, ValidationDelegate del)
{
    //errorstr = "";

    Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>))
    {
        //code
    }
```

As per my understanding `if (typeof(T) == typeof(List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>))` should return false for `IDEnq` (list of list) but it returns true!

Comment: You call it like this: `ValidateValue<List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>>(…)`, so `T` is `List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>`. As such, it’s not really surprising that `typeof(T)` equals to `typeof(List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>)`.

Comment: You are passing same list and getting its type so it will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check whether a type `t` is a list of lists, you could do something like this:

```
if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
{
    Type elementType = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    if (elementType.IsGenericType && elementType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        Console.WriteLine("t is a list of lists");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("t is just a list");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("t is not a list");
```

Answer (score 0):

> As per my understanding if (typeof(T) == typeof(List>)) should return false for IDEnq (list of list) but it returns true!

You are calling the generic type like this

```
 ValidateValue<List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>>(IDEnq, concaDel);
```

Generic type is this `List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>`. This has nothing to do with `IDEnq` since its `object`. So in when you call method like this, `T` is exactly type of `List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>` and the condition becomes true.

You can make your generic method like this. 
Now EnqTagList is T. You need to get the type of its elements.

```
private string ValidateValue<T>(T EnqTagList, ValidationDelegate del) 
{
    if (EnqTagList.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(List<HeaderTypeEnq<dynamic>>))
    {
     //code
    }
}
```